# Does every leading edge of a wave travel at the speed of light?

Tags: visible-light, waves, huygens-principle

I know this question may look like it doesn’t make sense. But at the end of the second paragraph of this article http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath242/kmath242.htm it looks like the author says every leading edge of a wave travels at the speed c. And right after giving an example of water. What did he mean really?

Comment: celeritas: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/celeritas or https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/celerit%C3%A0#Italian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context c is the characteristic wave speed, it's only the speed of light in an application to light waves.

Comment: Cool, I had no idea c could be used for any speed other than light

Comment: @RobertoValente - Just to be clear, in this context, $c$ is merely a *symbol* for *different* speed than that of light. Naturally, the speed of light can’t be used for any massive object, such as a water wave.

Answer (score 0):

it is very exciting to know that we can use c other than light speed but if we see the speed of the sound wave in air we found that it is very less than the speed of the light. I cant say about the leading edge of  the wave but every wave have some different speed according to their properties.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light 'c' is the speed limit of light.  Light and any other e/m wave only travel that speed in vacuum. When light enters a denser (light density not mass density) material it slows down.  When light enters our atmosphere it slows down to the speed it travels in air.  When it enters the glass of a window it slows down more.  When it comes out of the glass into the air in the room it speeds back to the same speed it travels in air.  So nothing 'always' travels at the speed c except e/m waves in vacuum.